# Textjoin and arrayformula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, flatten, textjoin

I am fighting to make this formula work on Gsheet.

So far I had it work by using

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,(UNIQUE(IF(D2:D=S2:S,E2:H,""))))
Or
=IF(AA2:AA="Approved", TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,unique(IF(D2:D=S2:S,E2:H,""))))
```

The formula works on the first line, however I'd like it to work as an array

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(AA2:AA="Approved", TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,unique(IF(D2:D=S2:S,E2:H,"")))))
```

When I add the array as shown above, it shows some result, but not all the result and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Any idea?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet. textjoin is not supported under arrayformula

Comment: @player0 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x3HrfTDndaLPCxBZeons_xkL6hWM9E72b_RYT0oYeV0/edit?usp=sharing

Basically column H would be data coming through a form and column I would show in a line where the person has access on which permit and how long.

Comment: The same person could have access to different rooms on different permits, that is why it is a bit tricky, for me anyway :)

Comment: @Jerome Could you share actual data from the form?  I can't figure out what the most upstream, raw data looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 IF(B2:B="",,{B2:B&"♦", C2:C&", "&D2:D&", "&E2:E&", "&F2:F&","}), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "♦")), ",$", ))
```

[image]